# Various ways of evaluating the polytropic index $n$

Tags: thermodynamics

The polytropic index is the index $n$ that characterizes a polytropic process, a process that obeys the relation:

$$pV^n=C.$$

I am looking for various methods for evaluating the value of this index.

I found the following formula:

$$n=\frac{ln\left( \frac{p_2}{p_1}\right)}{ln\left( \frac{p_2}{p_1}\right) - ln\left( \frac{T_2}{T_1}\right)}\tag 1$$

but what do we do in a situation where we want to determine the polytropic index but, perhaps, we don't know $T_2$? How many known variables do we need to uniquely determine $n$?

My question: What other expressions exist for evaluating $n$ besides $(1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is limited to $n=\ln(p_1/p_2)/\ln(V_2/V_1)$ unless an equation of state is available. For an ideal gas, $V\propto T/P$, so (1) is obtained through algebra. For that class of matter, $U\propto T$ (assuming that the reference zero for $U$ corresponds to $T=0$), so one could replace each $T$ with $U$.

Answer (score 0):

From your original equation, $$\ln{\left(\frac{P_2}{P_1}\right)}+n\ln{\left(\frac{V_2}{V_1}\right)}=0$$From the ideal gas law $$\ln{\left(\frac{P_2}{P_1}\right)}+\ln{\left(\frac{V_2}{V_1}\right)}-\ln{\left(\frac{T_2}{T_1}\right)}=0$$Any linear combination of these two equations can be used to explicitly express n.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found another way.

Consider a hypothetical process in an open system and let's say that the power supplied to do some polytropic process (a compression in this case, as power is being brought into the system) is equal in absolute values to the heat flux that would be obtained from some heat bath.

First lets write the First law for an open system:

$$\delta \Phi = dH +\delta P\tag1$$

Our hypothetical process is as described above with:

$$\delta P =-\delta \Phi.\tag2$$

Now we can say, using $(1)$ and the definition of enthalpy that

$$\delta \Phi = dH=q_m c_p dT\tag3$$

and

$$\delta P = q_m w_{teh}; \space w_{teh}= -\int_{p_1}^{p_2} v(p)dp\tag4$$

The last term, $w_{teh_{12}}$, is technical work, i.e. it can be understood as specific work during a process in an open system, units are $\frac{J}{kg}$.

One way of calculating $w_{teh}$ for a polytropic process is:

$$w_{teh_{12}}= \frac{nR_s}{n-1} (T_1-T_2)$$

Now we can finally write, from $(3)$ and $(4)$ into $(2)$:

$$q_mc_p(T_2-T_1)= -q_m w_{teh_{12}}= -q_m \frac{nR_s}{n-1} (T_1-T_2)$$

and after simplification we get:

$$c_p=\frac{nR_s}{n-1}$$

and finally:

$$n=\frac{c_p}{c_p-R_s}$$

as desired.